# LINQ orderby string with integer where 1,11,12,13 are not next to eachother?

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I have the following list in a table

```
Name
Server1
Server2
Server3
Server4
Server5
Server6
Server7
Server8
Server9
Server10
Server11
Server12
```

only problem is my linq satement orderby Name ascending puts them like the below

```
Server1
Server10
Server11
Server12
Server2
Server3
Server4
Server5
Server6
Server7
Server8
Server9
```

is there anyway to stop this?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For this special use case, you can either order by length and then name or parse the number and order by it:

```
// 1st alternative
servers.OrderBy(s => s.Length).OrderBy(s => s.Name);

// 2nd alternative
servers.OrderBy(s => Int32.Parse(s.Substring(6)));
```

Comment: Well, not in linq to entities. Got to enumerate first. Linq to entities won't appreciate Int32.Parse.

Comment: +1 for the "2nd alternative" because it is a viable solution.

Comment: Does linq to entities support .Substring in a store expression? Since which version?

Comment: @RaphaëlAlthaus You're right, but the example looks like the set of results isn't too big and all data is fetched, anyway. Therefore I won't mind a second enumeration, *in this special use case*.